# Put cookie on a WebView in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, post, cookies, xamarin.forms

I have the following plan in my Xamarin Project:

- The user enters his username and password on the MainPage.
- If data correct (API exists), navigate to a WebView and
  automatically login the user on this page.

The existing API (not public) delivers a System.Net.CookieCollection.

How can I realise my idea, using a POST-Request with those cookies? Here's my base:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class WebPage : ContentPage
{
    public WebPage(string url, CookieCollection cookies)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new MainPageViewModel();
        MyWebView.Source = "https://" + url;

    }
}
```

Kind regards,
localhorst27

Answer (score 6):

You will have to create a custom renderer for the `WebView` on both Android and iOS. That way you'll be able to inject the cookies into the Android `WebView` and iOS `UIWebView`. If you are not familiar with them, start here: [Introduction to Custom Renderers](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/introduction/)

When you're familiar with how renderers work, follow this post by [Christine Blanda](https://forums.xamarin.com/profile/10166/ChristineBlanda) on Xamarin forums: [Setting Cookies in a WebView](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/41039/setting-cookies-in-a-webview)

I'll also post the code here to make sure it's preserved in case the original post goes down.

**Android OnElementChanged**

```
var cookieManager = CookieManager.Instance;
cookieManager.SetAcceptCookie(true);
cookieManager.RemoveAllCookie();
var cookies = UserInfo.CookieContainer.GetCookies(new System.Uri(AppInfo.URL_BASE));
for (var i = 0; i < cookies.Count; i++)
{
    string cookieValue = cookies[i].Value;
    string cookieDomain = cookies[i].Domain;
    string cookieName = cookies[i].Name;
    cookieManager.SetCookie(cookieDomain, cookieName + "=" + cookieValue);
}
```

**iOS OnElementChanged**

```
// Set cookies here
var cookieUrl = new Uri(AppInfo.URL_BASE);
var cookieJar = NSHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage;
cookieJar.AcceptPolicy = NSHttpCookieAcceptPolicy.Always;
foreach (var aCookie in cookieJar.Cookies)
{
    cookieJar.DeleteCookie(aCookie);
}

var jCookies = UserInfo.CookieContainer.GetCookies(cookieUrl);
IList<NSHttpCookie> eCookies = 
                   (from object jCookie in jCookies 
                    where jCookie != null 
                    select (Cookie) jCookie 
                    into netCookie select new NSHttpCookie(netCookie)).ToList();
cookieJar.SetCookies(eCookies.ToArray(), cookieUrl, cookieUrl);
```

Comment: CookieManager does not have a property named Instance. Can you explain how it might work? Plus, my compiler cannot handle AppInfo.URL_BASE

Comment: The link on the forum provided some key information.  Ultimately I used some of the code presented here but visit the forum for a full understanding.  This worked.