# Save session storage of a website in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Whenever I navigate through the pages in xamarin, the page having a webview loses the session storage of the website. Is there a way to get and store the session so that whenever I navigate to the webview page, the website session storage won't be lost.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could check the way via custom renderer in the link below. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42853636/put-cookie-on-a-webview-in-xamarin/42854428

Comment: Thanks but that won't solve the problem

Comment: What is the code you used? Did you get some errors?